# replacing bone rotation with same value, changes value -360 degrees, causing side effects

Tags: animation, bones

I have a problem where if I slightly change an IK bone rotation slightly (or even replace single keyframe with exact same value), the new keyframe value shifts by -360 degrees from 201 to -159.  This doesn't seem at first to be a problem, but because of (perhaps) dependent FK bones Limit Rotation, the effects on prior frames causes "great convulsions" in actual rotation.

Here we see the initial rotation:

[image]

and also the the GE:

[image]

which then does the zip around the rotation sphere to -159:

[image]

If I edit the GE value and say *value*+360, it gets corrected.   How can I stop this headache from happening, oh great gurus?

Example here: [image]

Here is an animated GIF:

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  How are you changing rotation?  Does it flip 360 degrees before "replace single keyframe" or only after?  What Blender version?

Comment: i am sorry, but if you directly exclude me (oh great gurus) that i think i mustn't help, is that your intention? 

Comment: @Nathan -- immediately after I select Replace Single Keyframe from context menu, the value in the GE changes from 2-1 to -159.   Not yet in the bone rotation until I change frame (e.g., frame left, then frame right).  v4.0.2.

Comment: @james_t Opening your file In 4.01, I right click on sidebar/rotation/x and select "replace single keyframe."  It remains at 201.  I advance a frame and then go back a frame (with arrow key hotkeys.)  It remains at 201 in both sidebar and graph editor.  Maybe 4.02 issue, but I doubt it....  I think there's something you're failing to describe about *how* you're doing things in a way to reproduce.

Comment: @Nathan -- I added a video at the end of my question.

Comment: @james_t Have to reset the 701 key to -159 first, but it's not happening to me.  Maybe a 4.02 bug after all.  (Didn't see any reason to bother with the 4.02 download.)

Comment: @Nathan -- forgot to say THANK YOU A MILLION before.   still a problem in my 3.62.   I need to buy more salt to throw over my shoulder to chase the demons away.  I can always waste time conjuring up some script triggered by ??? for some compensating fix or just go to bed and rest LOL.  As an retired java programmer, I can bare Python my way through the basics.

Comment: Dunno, I guess it's possible it's something in user prefs.  Restore to factory default  (or just reinstall) is usually a good idea in cases like this.